# Keyboard hide UITableView issue

Tags: objective-c

I have a view controller on which I have a table view, in table view each row have text field when i tap on the text field keyboard appear and hide the table view, and then can't see the editing, how can I fix this issue? I put observer that fix the alignment of view controller but it didn't work here is the code..

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                           object:nil];
 return YES;
}

-(void)keyboardWillShow {
// Animate the current view out of the way
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^ {
    self.viewFrame =  CGRectMake(0, -160, 320, 480);
}];
}
```

Comment: u need to set contentOffset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
you have to write below code, it will hide and show keyboard.   

====>.h file: declare one UITextField as below:

UITextField *actifText;

====>.m file:

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  // Register notification when the keyboard will be show
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                           object:nil];

// Register notification when the keyboard will be hide
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                           object:nil];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{            
[textField resignFirstResponder];
return YES;
}

-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

-(void) keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note
{
// Get the keyboard size
CGRect keyboardBounds;
[[note.userInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] getValue: &keyboardBounds];

// Detect orientation
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
CGRect frame = self.tblName.frame;

// Start animation
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3f];

// Reduce size of the Table view 
if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    frame.size.height -= keyboardBounds.size.height;
else 
    frame.size.height -= keyboardBounds.size.width;

// Apply new size of table view
self.tblName.frame = frame;

// Scroll the table view to see the TextField just above the keyboard
if (self.actifText)
{
    CGRect textFieldRect = [self.tblName convertRect:self.actifText.bounds fromView:self.actifText];
    [self.tblName scrollRectToVisible:textFieldRect animated:NO];
}

[UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
self.actifText = nil;
}
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
   self.actifText = textField;
}

-(void) keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)note
{
// Get the keyboard size
CGRect keyboardBounds;
[[note.userInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] getValue: &keyboardBounds];

// Detect orientation
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
CGRect frame = self.tblName.frame;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3f];

// Reduce size of the Table view 
if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    frame.size.height += keyboardBounds.size.height;
else 
    frame.size.height += keyboardBounds.size.width;

// Apply new size of table view
self.tblName.frame = frame;

[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: its work but when i tap on text view which is on the top of table view then table view move upward every time when i tap on text view..

Comment: code is written for that because if data is more, at that time it will me automatically move upside. if you dont want that then remove // Scroll the table view to see the TextField just above the keyboard
if (self.actifText)
{
    CGRect textFieldRect = [self.tblName convertRect:self.actifText.bounds fromView:self.actifText];
    [self.tblName scrollRectToVisible:textFieldRect animated:NO];
} from -(void) keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note method

Answer (score 0):

When you tap on some textfield inside cell, you must know current cell's indexpath, so when keyboard is shown, you can focus it.

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[textField superview].superview;
    NSIndexPath *idxPath = [table indexPathForCell:cell];
    selectedIndex = idxPath.row;//instance variable

    return YES;
}

-(void)keyboardWillShow {

[table scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:selectedIndex inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];

}
```

Also add following line to `ViewDidLoad`, keeping in mind to observe when keyboard have appeared. If you use `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`, first `keyboardWillShow` will be called followed by `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:` which is wrong.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

and set

```
textfield.delegate = self;
```

in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` while creating textfield. It will call required methods.